# null intent redelivered to Service onStartCommand()

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-service, android-intentservice

In the Android documentation, the Service's "`onStartCommand()`" has an intent given as a `param`, that according to the docs:

"the `Intent` supplied to `startService(Intent)`, as given. This may be null if the service is being restarted after its process has gone away, and it had previously returned anything except `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY`."

However, the return value `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` is supposed to return the original intent when restarting a service.

Can anyone explain why an `intent` can be null, even if the `flag` was set to `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`?

Comment: +1: I'm observing the same behaviour: START_REDELIVER_INTENT gives null intents. However, most of the devices are of less well-known brands like Alps, Tecno and Wiko. I haven't seen any mainstream brands so far.

Comment: Actually, looking on some other issue I see that Google's own com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService crashes with NullPointerException in onStartCommand() on **Itel** devices. And it looks like they do a intent.getAction() without checking if intent is null. They use START_NOT_STICKY where the service isn't supposed to be restarted (which should avoid null intents).

Answer (score 2):

Are you possibly confusing [START_FLAG_REDELIVERY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_FLAG_REDELIVERY) with [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT)?  Your post says, "the return value `START_FLAG_REDELIVERY`".  That constant is not one of the values returned from [onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)), it is one of the bit values passed into `onStartCommand` as the `flags` parameter.  `START_FLAG_REDELIVERY` and `START_STICKY` both have value of 1.  If you mistakenly have `return START_FLAG_REDELIVERY` at the end of `onStartCommand()`, the service will restart in sticky mode with a null intent if there are no start commends pending.